# Django. Одновременное сохранение экземпляра записи БД несколькими пользователями

Tags: база-данных, django, view, запись

Необходимо реализовать механизм одновременного сохранения одной и той же записи в БД несколькими пользователями. Принцип следующий:
Заявка открывается несколькими пользователями. Модель заявки имеет поле `saveDate`, которое хранит дату и время последнего сохранения. При открытии пользователь сохраняет параметр `saveDate` и перед записью в БД
проверяет его, сравнивая с экземпляром заявки из БД. Если `saveDate` не изменился - производится запись в БД, иначе пользователь получает сообщение об изменении заявки в ходе редактирования другим пользователем.
Пытаюсь реализовать этот механизм через `view`-представление, где запоминается `saveDate`, однако, т.к. `view` вызывается два раза - первый при инициализации формы для редактирования, второй - при записи формы. И `saveDate`, естественно, в данном случае не сохраняется.

**Модель:**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    saveDate = DateTimeField()
```

**View:**

```
def entry(request, pk):
    ...
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=pk)
    save_date = entry.saveDate # сохраняем маркер даты, времени последнего редактирования
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        oldEntry = Entry.objects.get(id=pk)
        if save_date == oldEntry.saveDate: # проверяем маркер на изменение 
            entryForm.save()
            ...
        else: 
            # сообщение пользователю об изменении исходных данных
```

Как в данном случае можно использовать маркер сохранения `saveDate`?

Может на этот случай есть стандартные методы блокировки записи БД при одновременном редактировании несколькими пользователями?